# Skip GORM Domain class validations

Tags: validation, grails, grails-orm

I have a Domain class with associations and some transient fields. I also have custom validations in the Parent as well as child domain class. I created a Parent Domain class object and want to skip the validations on all the fields even on child domain class. I gave `object.save(validate:false, deepValidate:false, flush:true)` but still custom validators are executed.

I am using Grails 2.2.1

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I reported the same problem in the JIRA issue [here](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10699).  Sadly it has had no activity yet.

Comment: @ubiquibacon I think that JIRA's are prioritized by votes, so you need more :-)